# why #include <iostream> is not used in driver development

Tags: c++

```c
#include <DriverSpecs.h>
_Analysis_mode_(_Analysis_code_type_user_code_)

#define INITGUID
//#include<iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <strsafe.h>
#include <cfgmgr32.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "public.h"
```

When I tried to use `<iostream>` in a sample driver solution I got an error.
I'd like to know if is it possible to get input or output while a driver is running.

Comment: Are you sure this is C++ and not C? You have standard IO header from C included, you can use that instead of `iostream`

Comment: @AlexF  why do you say that you have wondered on how windows.h and stdlib.h are workings?